# how to replace a single newline with a double newline in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

My question is simple, what do I enter into find-and-replace on google docs so that I can replace a single newline with a double newline so that there is an empty space between my paragraphs? I already know that I can search \n with regular expressions on, but how can I set it to replace it with two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do that in search and replace UI.

I'd recommend using `Apps Script` and using this code.

#### Code:

```
function addAdditionalNewLine() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
    .getBody()
    .getParagraphs()
    .forEach(function (paragraph){
      paragraph.appendText("\n");
    });
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Add New Lines', 'addAdditionalNewLine')
    .addToUi();
}
```

#### Note:

- What the code does is add a new line every end of every paragraph.
- Additionally, I added a custom menu whenever the document is refreshed/opened (You may need to refresh the document after saving the script):
  [image: output]
- Please make sure to have the necessary permissions first on the editor by running the function `addAdditionalNewLine` manually.

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

#### Output (after running clicking "Add New Lines" menu):

[image: output1]